# How to keep the header on the next page when the table is too long and causes a page break while printing the header and table in vuecli?

Tags: html, css, vuex

I need to print a header and a table using vuecli, but when the table is too long, it causes page breaks. I need to bring the header to the second page when there is a page break.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.